# Propel cannot access PEAR log file

Tags: xampp, pear, propel

I've got a propel installation on a XAMPP set up. I've been having a somewhat smooth coding process, but needed to make a change to my PHP.ini file, so did so then restarted apache. I had not shutdown the apache process for a while, and I now get an error when I try to use Propel:

```
Warning: fopen(/path/to/propel.log) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file    or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/pear/share/pear/Log/file.php on line 216

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General   error: 1017 Can't find file: './ghir/intervention.frm' (errno: 13)' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php:1321 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php(1321): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php(1164): ModelCriteria->doSelect(Object(PropelPDO)) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/model.php(41): ModelCriteria->find() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/js/globals.php(38): GHD->__construct('175') #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/index.php(78): require_once('/Applications/X...') #5 {main} Next exception 'PropelException' with message 'Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT intervention.ID, intervention.NAME, intervention.ABBREVIATION, intervention.DESCRIPTION, intervention. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ghir-php/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php on line 1324
```

The xamppfiles/pear/share/pear/Log/file.php does exist, and is readable and writable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of updating your question with your answer, post an answser and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The top error was misleading, not actually the problem. A few of my tables had been corrupted, and the MySQL server couldn't find the .fmr's. I deleted the tables (from the filesystem, not via DROP), then restored them to older versions. Worked fine after that.